# Ruby erb template 'or' operator

Tags: erb, puppet

I have a puppet manifest which uses an erb template.

This is the correct syntax according to the documentation, and it works perfectly.

```
<% if foo != bar %>
  derp
<% else %> 
  herp
<% end %>
```

How can I combine the if statement with an 'or' operator?

Here are the following syntaxes that I have tried, however they return an error:

```
<% if foo != bar  or  if slurp != burp %>
  derp
<% else %> 
  herp
<% end %> 

Error: Could not run: /etc/puppet/modules/gitlab/templates/gitlab.yml.6-7-stable.erb:275: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
```

I tried changing <% to <%% since this is mentioned in the [puppet docs.](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/templating.html)

```
<%% if foo != bar  or  if slurp != burp %%>
  derp
<% else %> 
  herp
<% end %> 

Error: Could not run: /etc/puppet/modules/gitlab/templates/gitlab.yml.6-7-stable.erb:241: syntax error, unexpected keyword_else, expecting $end
;  else ; _erbout.concat "\n    derp   "
   ^
```

I've tried splitting the if-s

```
<% if foo != bar  %> or  <% if slurp != burp %>
  derp
<% else %> 
  herp
<% end %> 
Error: Could not run: /etc/puppet/modules/gitlab/templates/gitlab.yml.6-7-stable.erb:275: syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end
; _erbout.force_encoding(__ENCODING__)
                                  ^
```

Comment: ERB *is* Ruby and `if foo != bar or if slurp != burp else end` is invalid Ruby. Try running (the Ruby in the ERB tags) directly on the REPL.

Comment: Because your syntax of writing `if` block was not expected by MRI. Go to the link, I cited in my answer to see how to write the `if` block in Ruby.

Comment: @user2864740 As I mentioned in the question, this is a puppet manifest. There is no way to run the code on the REPL.

Comment: @spuder Being a puppet manifest is irrelevant to running the relevant code on the REPL. I've added an answer showing the resulting *Ruby* code (again, ERB *is* Ruby) and why the "ERB" generates said syntax error.

Answer (score 6):

There is an extra `if`. The correct syntax is:

```
<% if foo != bar  or slurp != burp %> 
  derp
<% else %> 
  herp
<% end %>
```

But your ones didn't work as your `if-else` construct was wrong. Read the documentation of [`if-else`](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/files/keywords_rb.html#M000022) construct.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby syntax for if/else blocks is:

if *conditional*

The *conditional* can include any logical operators such as 'or', 'and', '&', '|', '&&', '||'.

However, it **can not** contain another if block as your example has:

if foo != bar  or  **if** slurp != burp

Comment: `if` (and also the `or`) can accept *any* expression. The problem in this case is that the second `if` (which is itself an expression!) yields to too many `if`-expressions being opened, for not enough `end` keywords.

Answer (score 0):

ERB *is* Ruby<sup>1</sup>. ERB simply extracts the Ruby in the tags and the "inline text" into a mash-up of code and in-line string/output building to yield intermediate Ruby which is then executed.

As such, extracting the *actual Ruby* (as executed by ERB) looks like:

```
if foo != bar or if slurp != burp
  # some inconsequential ERB magic to output "derp"
else
  # some inconsequential ERB magic to output "herp"
end
```

Now, filling in the non-interesting parts with dummy expressions yields the following. (Ignore that the strings are always truthy-expressions; the problem is a *Syntax Error*.)

```
if "hello" or if "world"
else
end
```

And this yields the expected error message (see [ideone demo](http://ideone.com/n69C77)).

> prog.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected $end

Well .. *why*?

It's because there are *two* `if`-expressions<sup>2</sup>, but only *one* is closed and the code has been parsed as though grouping parenthesis have been added.

```
if "hello" or (if "world"
else
end) # <-- no `end` for `if "hello"`!
```

The fix is then simply to remove the nested `if`-expression.

```
# no extra `if` here, so only looking for one `end` below
if "hello" or "world"
else
end
```

---

<sup>1</sup> A more correct statement would be that the code in ERB tags *is* Ruby, and ERB internally *generates* Ruby, using the content of ERB tags directly. This differs from other template engines which introduce their own syntax and parser. ERB *is* Ruby.

<sup>2</sup> Ruby also supports the `expr if expr` (and `if expr then .. end`) forms. Regardless, the fundamental issue is the addition of the second unnecessary `if`.